# GridView with specific columns?

Tags: c#, gridview, datatable

I need to display a gridview with 5 rows. The grid will only have two columns, first the textbox and the second textarea. The grid might/might not have the text in each row, and if there isn't any result the grid is suppose to show empty fields with 5 rows. The grid will be binded with list of employee object. The first textbox will be employee name and the second textarea will be employee description.
The employee object:
EmployeeId, EmployeeName, EmployeeDescription.

The list of employee object will only be less or equal to 5 results.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Set `AutoGenerateColumns="false"` on your GridView, then define the columns you want.  If you want to include TextBox / TextArea controls, you'll need to use a template field.